# Unintuitive observation by Rumford

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I was reading [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3143157?read-now=1&seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents) paper on the work of Count Rumford in developing the modern view of heat as a form of energy and not some kind of fluid. In that I encountered this experiment.

> Say you had two cylinders B(say at temp. 44°C) and A(at 0°C). Now you place a thermoscope (which was at 22°C) in the middle.

> The paper says that there was no change in the reading of the thermoscope as the heat gained from B was almost equal to heat lost to A.
> When they blackened the surface of B using a candle's flame they noticed that the reading of the thermoscope started to increase as the intensity of radiation from B got enhanced (I am not sure how ?).
> Now when they blackened both the cylinders they again saw no change in the temperature of the thermoscope which is unintuitive.

[image]

Rumford himself posed this question to the supporters of Caloric model of heat to explain the invariance in the temperature in the last scenario.

**Now we have accepted heat as a form of energy. So how do we explain each of the above observations made by Rumford ?**

Comment: Heat is being transferred by radiation. Changing the emissivity of one face changes the flux relative to the other.

Answer (score 10):

By blackening the surface of the cylinders, their emissivity $\varepsilon$ is increased. When B is blackened, the thermal radiation it emits will increase in accordance with the Stefan-Boltzmann law $P = A \varepsilon \sigma T^4$ (where $A$ is area, $\sigma$ the Stefan-Boltzmann constant, and $T$ temperature). This results in the thermoscope becoming hotter and the measured temperature increasing. When A is also blackened its absorptivity will increase (as this is equal to its emissivity). Consequently, the thermoscope now loses more heat to A and the measured temperature is approximately the same as it was originally.

Comment: Which is the absorptivity that should appear in your formula ? That of cylinder A, B or the thermoscope?

Comment: Interestingly, if you assume that the thermoscope is a flat disc of area equal to that of the end of the cylinders and that the emissivity of all surfaces is 1, then the thermoscope will only be at 50C if about 88% of the radiation from each cylinder falls on it. If 100% of the radiation from the cylinders falls on it, it will be at 61C. If only half the radiation from each cylinder falls on it, then its temperature will only be about 8C. (All these in thermal equilibrium.)

Comment: @Mauricio in the above, the formula is used to explain the increase in thermal radiation emitted by B as its emissivity increases. Therefore, it is the emissivity of that body that I was referring to specifically in the formula. Similar formulas would be applicable to emission by A and C (which would need to be considered to quantitatively determine the thermoscope temperature).

Answer (score 7):

The answer lies in radiation absorption and reflection. All bodies absorb and emit radiation. A perfect black body absorbs all radiation falling on it and emits radiation dependent on its temperature. This property of a black body caused a crisis in physics at the end of the nineteenth century and was solved by Max Planck who, in doing so, introduced the first quantum theory.  [ultraviolet catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe)

When a black body is heated up it emits radiation according to Planck’s formula. As you know, a hot body appears first red, then yellow, then white as its temperature increases. Oddly enough the sun is an almost perfect black body. That sounds like a contradiction, but it isn’t, as the spectrum of radiation from the sun fits almost perfectly the spectrum of a black body at 5800K. [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)
[image: black body spectrum]

A white body reflects most radiation, and is also a poor emitter of radiation. Reflective surfaces, like most metals, act similarly.

In Rumford’s first experiment, with the two cylinders, the thermoscope is absorbing heat from the hot cylinder at about the same rate as it is emitting radiation to be absorbed by the cold cylinder, so its temperature remains constant. When the hot cylinder is blackened, its albedo is reduced and it emits much more radiation, while the cold cylinder will not absorb this heat, but is reflecting heat back to the thermoscope causing the thermoscope to  heat up. When the cold cylinder is also blackened it now absorbs more heat from the thermoscope, a similar amount of heat as that emitted by the hot cylinder, so the temperature of the thermoscope stays at 50C.

Answer (score 7):

### Rumford's account

I was waiting for a source, but I finally found it myself. It was published here :

- Thompson, Benjamin. "An enquiry concerning the nature of heat, and the mode of its communication." Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London 94 (1804): experiment on page 126. doi:[10.1098/rstl.1804.0009](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1804.0009)
- A summarized account can be found here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3143157

In his account Rumford gives some additional remarks:

- There is air in the room
- The temperatures are different, given by $T_A=32$°F ($0$°C, $273$ K), $T_B=112$°F ($44$°C, $317$ K) and $T_C=72$°F ($22$°C, $295$ K) for thermoscope and surroundings.

### A simplified model

The heat flow transfer between three objects can get very complicated  and non-intuitive, especially when geometries are involved. This is even more complicated if you want to account for the air in the room.

I would consider here simplified version, where I replace the two cylinders and the thermoscope by three gray-body parallel planes in vacuum. I will also assume that the fluxes can be treated independently between A and the thermoscope, and the thermoscope and B (this is never the case in real life).

The heat flux (per surface area) reaching the thermoscope from $B$ is
$$\Phi_B=\frac{\sigma(T_B^4-T_C^4)}{\epsilon_B^{-1}+\epsilon_C^{-1}-1}$$
where $\epsilon_i$ is the emissivity of plane $i=A,B,C$ ($C$ is for thermoscope) and $\sigma$ is Stefan–Boltzmann constant. Derivation here: https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node136.html
while the flux leaving the thermoscope towards $A$ is
$$\Phi_A=\frac{\sigma(T_C^4-T_A^4)}{\epsilon_C^{-1}+\epsilon_A^{-1}-1}$$

If we choose ideal emissivity $\epsilon_C=1$, we have that the ratio between the two is:
$$\tau=\frac{\Phi_B}{\Phi_A}=\frac{\epsilon_B(T_B^4-T_C^4)}{\epsilon_A(T_C^4-T_A^4)}$$

Now for the temperatures let us use those of Rumford, and set $\epsilon_A=\epsilon_B$. We have that the ratio is about $\tau_1=1.25>1$ (our ideal thermoscope heats). I think that the temperatures chosen by Rumford were such that the *real* thermoscope in air was in thermal equilibrium (and thus the ratio was even closer to 1). Note that a different set of temperatures will not reproduce his experiment. For the purpose of this question let us say that this 0.25 extra in $\tau_1$ is small and negligible, at least for the sensitivity that we require.

When the surface of B gets blackened, the emissivity of B gets higher, let us say 10 times higher, so $\epsilon_B=10\epsilon_A$ and we get a new ratio $\tau_2=10\tau_1$, where $\tau_1$ is the original case before getting B blacknened. The ratio has increased too by a factor of 10, so let us say that in this case the heat flux is detectable

Now it is easy to see that for the third case, when the two cylinders are blackened, now we have again $\epsilon_B=\epsilon_A$, thus the ratio becomes again $\tau_3=10\tau_1/10=\tau_1$. Which means again that the change is not detectable.

### Some additional notes

Note that if we worked out instead the heat exchange from A to B (no thermoscope), then there is always an important heat exchange between the two,  the heat flux is larger when both surfaces are blackened (which led to my previous failed answer).

<s>It is unfortunate that we do not have</s> Rumford's paper documents many different cases, probably he also tried the case where A is blackened and B isn't. In that case the thermoscope would have gotten colder.

One could argue that the extra 0.25 in $\tau_1$ for the first case is proportional to the flux on the thermoscope and is not the same as the extra 0.25 in $\tau_3$ for the third case. However, that is not that important, the extra 9 in $\tau_2$ is what makes the difference (also $\tau_1$ and $\tau_3$ were probably closer to 1 in the experiment). Here are the different ratios for (total flux case 1/total flux case 1, total flux case 2/total flux case 1, total flux case 3/total flux case 1): (1, 46,10).